# Using sIFR in nyroModal lightbox

Tags: sifr, lightbox, nyromodal

I'm using sIFR in a page that's being popped up in a nyroModal lightbox, but when the page is displayed, the sIFR objects aren't being shown. What do I need to do to get them to show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea will be to use the endShowContent callback from nyroModal to sIFR your text.

```
$.fn.nyroModal.settings.endShowContent = function(elts, settings) {
    $('YOUR SELECTOR', elts.content).media(function(el, options) {
        // What you need to do
    });
};
```

Hope it will help.
If you still have some trouble, come on the google code page to post your issue: http://code.google.com/p/nyromodal/